# Understanding the following statement regarding set theory;

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If the cardinality of X is less than the cardinality of Y, then there exists an injection from X to Y but not a surjection.

I understand why there cannot be a surjection, but why does there have to be an injection?

i.e if you have X is the set {1,2} and Y is the set {3,4,5}, then the above would still be true even if an injection did not exist?

Comment: An injection does exist: the map that takes $1$ to $3$ and $2$ to $5$ is one of several injections from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @John: Six, actually. There are $3$ choices for the image of $1$, and then there are $2$ for the image of $2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of the ZFC axioms that for any sets $X,Y$ there exists:

- either an injection $X \to Y$ or an injection $Y \to X$, and
- either a surjection $X \to Y$ or a surjection $Y \to X$.

But for finite sets, abstract principles aren't needed to see that injections exist. With your example sets, $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y = \{3,4,5\}$, there are several (ok, 6) injections $X\to Y$, for example $\{(1,3), (2,4) \}$.

Comment: Ah yes ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to clarify, you're welcome.